# Sort by part of filename

Tags: php, glob

I have a `$inhalte = glob("*.jpg");` listing pictures in a directory. Those files look like this

```
Constant1-Constant2-Input-ToBeSorted1-Date1.jpg
Constant1-Constant2-Output-ToBeSorted2-Date2.jpg
Constant1-Constant2-Input-ToBeSorted3-Date3.jpg
Constant1-Constant2-Output-ToBeSorted4-Date4.jpg
...
```

They should be sorted by `ToBeSorted` alphabetically. Sorting them by name a/descendingly does not work, as the `Input/Output` interferes.

How do I accomplish that?

Comment: If there's a pattern you can identify in your filenames, you could use regex (e.g.: `/(?>Output|Input)-([^-]\w*)/`) to extract the part you're interested in `$1` and use it for a user defined sorting algorithm https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php.

Comment: @BojanBedrač I did a `usort($inhalte, create_function('$a,$b', '$n1 = explode("-",basename ($a))[3];$n2 = explode("-",basename ($b))[3];return strcmp($n1, $n2);'));` which worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[strstr](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.strstr.php) provides the string behind 'ToBeSorted' and helps to make a simple comparison for [usort()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.usort).

```
//$inhalte is the array supplied by glob()
usort($inhalte, function($a, $b){
  return strstr($a,"ToBeSorted") <=> strstr($b,"ToBeSorted");
});
```